# TurtleBot "move_base/goal" Problem

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, move-base, move-base-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishing a MoveBaseActionGoal.msg on the move_base/goal topic sometimes fails. Sometimes, though the goal appears on "rostopic echo move_base/goal", the TurtleBot will not move.

Can anyone resolve the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33950/turtlebot-%22move_base/goal%22-problem/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, you should not send MoveBaseActionGoal messages directly. Instead, use [actionlib](http://ros.org/wiki/actionlib). Have a look at [this](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) tutorial.

In your case, unless you can provide more information, I think it is hard to say what the actual problem is. Does rxconsole show something? My guess is that you don't fill in some information actionlib relies on correctly. Using actionlib instead of constructing the goal by hand would prevent that.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2012-05-15**:
Thanks a lot!